Ho do I reset a mat-radio-group when clicking on an already selected item? (toggle functionality)
I have a list of items in a mat-radio group. I would like a group-wide toggle functionality when I click on an already selected radio button.
If A is selected and I click B then B becomes selected.
If I click on B after that, then nothing become selected
Here is an example with a button to reset the radio group. I would like the same behaviour when the clicked radio button corresponds to the already selected value
https://stackblitz.com/edit/reset-radio-value?file=src%2Fmain.ts

usually radio button always has a value selected, could you add more details if possible minimal reproducible code

radio buttons can have an undetermined state and can be reset. I've added a demo

They can be reset but we're mixing checkbox and radio behavior. I'd add another control that resets the group to make it consistent.

We can add a click event to the element mat-radio-button there we evaluate the logic to uncheck.
Keyboard events are not consistent, you might want to check that.
<mat-radio-group [ngModel]="radioValue" (ngModelChange)="changeRadio({}, $event)" aria-label="Select an option">
  <mat-radio-button tabindex="0" [value]="1" (click)="changeRadio($event, 1)">Option 1</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button tabindex="0" [value]="2" (click)="changeRadio($event, 2)">Option 2</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>

We simply check if the previous value matches the current value, then we set it to null.
changeRadio(e: any, radioSelected: number) {
  e?.preventDefault();
  e?.stopPropagation();
  if (this.radioValue && this.radioValue === radioSelected) {
    this.radioValue = null;
    return;
  }
  this.radioValue = radioSelected;
}

Full Code:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <mat-radio-group [ngModel]="radioValue" (ngModelChange)="changeRadio({}, $event)" aria-label="Select an option">
      <mat-radio-button tabindex="0" [value]="1" (click)="changeRadio($event, 1)">Option 1</mat-radio-button>
      <mat-radio-button tabindex="0" [value]="2" (click)="changeRadio($event, 2)">Option 2</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
    <br>
    <button (click)="radioValue=null">Reset</button>
  `,
  imports: [FormsModule, MatRadioModule],
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  radioValue: number | null = null;

  changeRadio(e: any, radioSelected: number) {
    e?.preventDefault();
    e?.stopPropagation();
    if (this.radioValue && this.radioValue === radioSelected) {
      this.radioValue = null;
      return;
    }
    this.radioValue = radioSelected;
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
